# sed multiline recursive pattern substitution

Tags: text-processing, sed

From the following input:

```
serial0/0
SSL disabled
eth0/0
SSL enabled
SSL only
eth0/1
SSL disabled
bgroup0
SSL enabled
eth0/2
SSL disabled
eth0/3
SSL disabled
eth0/4
SSL disabled
bgroup1
SSL disabled
bgroup2
SSL disabled
bgroup3
SSL disabled
vlan1
SSL enabled
null
SSL disabled
```

I am trying to obtain a colon separated list in which if the next line of the input begins with "SSL", it gets appended to the previous line, so the output would be like so:

```
serial0/0:SSL disabled
eth0/0:SSL enabled:SSL only
eth0/1:SSL disabled
bgroup0:SSL enabled
eth0/2:SSL disabled
eth0/3:SSL disabled
eth0/4:SSL disabled
bgroup1:SSL disabled
bgroup2:SSL disabled
bgroup3:SSL disabled
vlan1:SSL enabled
null:SSL disabled
```

As you can see in the second line of this ideal output, the case when more than one line starts with "SSL" should be considered. Based on [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) classic `sed` guide, I came up with the following `sed` script:

```
sed -r '/^SSL/! {
        :again
        N
        s/(.*)\n(SSL.*)/\1:\2/
        t again
    }'
```

Which makes sense to me but returns the following output:

```
serial0/0:SSL disabled
eth0/0
SSL enabled
SSL only
eth0/1:SSL disabled
bgroup0
SSL enabled
eth0/2:SSL disabled
eth0/3
SSL disabled
eth0/4:SSL disabled
bgroup1
SSL disabled
bgroup2:SSL disabled
bgroup3
SSL disabled
vlan1:SSL enabled
null
SSL disabled
```

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A much easier solution:

```
sed -z 's/\nSSL/:SSL/g'
```

The `-z` says to use NUL as a line separator - effectively making the entire stream appear as one line to `sed`. It then simple replaces a `\nSSL` sequence with a `:SSL` sequence, effectively combining lines the way you wish.

Comment: A large caveat to this solution is that it won't start processing anything until the input is terminated, which means if you're using it as part of a pipeline, you won't see any output from `sed` until the command providing the input to `sed` finishes.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with any `sed` flavor, no need to slurp the whole file into memory just use a classic `N;P;D` cycle and a branch:

```
sed ':b;$!N;s/\nSSL/:SSL/;tb;P;D' infile
```

This pulls in the `N`ext line, attempts to `s`ubstitute - if successful it branches back to `:b` else it `P`rints and then `D`eletes up to the newline character, restarting the cycle.